# SSL Handshake fail when trying to download a file from an FTPS

Tags: swift, ssl, ftps, cfnetwork

## What I'm doing?

I'm working on a iOS app which is going to download files from an FTPS server. For this purpose I'm using the library [FilesProvider](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FilesProvider).

### Error description

Until now I successfully achieve to login in the server, list files and search for files, but I'm getting the following **error** when trying to download one of the files:

```
File Provider <FilesProvider.FTPFileProvider: 0x283c23900> shouldDoOperation Copy with action Copying and destination file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/90AF4202-18C1-4A41-B461-4FB262FD39B9/tmp/B13A8110-C919-48E4-8BD9-E684929310C0.tmp
2020-05-27 14:35:39.372289+0200 MyApp[548:100799] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C13:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
2020-05-27 14:35:39.595959+0200 MyApp[548:99892] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
2020-05-27 14:35:39.596380+0200 MyApp[548:99892] TCP Conn 0x28274f540 SSLHandshake failed (-9806)
File Provider <FilesProvider.FTPFileProvider: 0x283c23900> Failed for operation Copy with action Copying and destination file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/90AF4202-18C1-4A41-B461-4FB262FD39B9/tmp/B13A8110-C919-48E4-8BD9-E684929310C0.tmp
Throwing Error: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-9806 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

**FTPFileProvider** is an object created with the library I've mention above that handles the FTP connection. That provider looks like:

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "ftps://X.X.X.X") else { return } // I have to use an IP address instead of a domain
var provider = FTPFileProvider(baseURL: url, mode: .default, credential: credential, cache: .none)
provider.delegate = self
provider.fileOperationDelegate = self // This delegate is only for print the first line of the error
provider.serverTrustPolicy = .disableEvaluation
```

After creating the provider of the connection, I've been able to do login in the server, search some files and get the file list. I'm doing that with this function:

```swift
provider.searchFiles(path: remotePath, recursive: false, query: predicate, foundItemHandler: { (file) in print("File found with name: \(file.name)") }, completionHandler: { (list, error) in
        if error != nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onError(error!)
            }
        } else {
            var files:[String] = []
            for f in list {
                (f.isRegularFile) ? files.append(f.name) : nil
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                onSucess(files)
            }
        }
})
```

When running that search I get this warning:

```
2020-05-27 14:45:51.831812+0200 MyApp[555:102153] [] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4:1] Socket SO_ERROR [54: Connection reset by peer]
```

But I successfully get an output in `onSuccess(files)`. The returned value for `files` is:

```
["20200527-093234-28346646454.pdf", "20200527-105409-28346646454.pdf"]
```

After that search, I try to download one of the files is when I get the **error** describe at the beginning of this post. For do the download I have the following function:

```swift
provider.copyItem(path: "\(remotePath)/\(file)", to: localPath.absoluteString, overwrite: true) { (error) in
    if error != nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            onError(error!)
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            onSuccess(localPath)
        }
    }
}
```

### What I've try

- As you could see above, the object who connect to the server has disabled the SSL certificate checks. That's why I can do the login and search for the files.
- I've configure the `Info.plist` disabling `ATS`:

```xml
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key> <!-- Because I wan't to allow everything  -->
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key> <!-- Because seems like library uses AVFoundation framework -->
        <true/>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key> <!-- Because I'm using a public IP instead a domain -->
      <true/>
    </dict>
```

**Neither of that options works.**

### Some facts

- Domain DNS entry is not going to be created for now. I can't do anything about this.
- Server do have a valid SSL certificate.
- I can successfully login, list files and search for files. (I just can't download)
- I didn't try to upload a file. App isn't going to do it.

### Questions

- Why login, listing or searching files works but I get that error when trying to download?
- Any idea on how to fix it? Any workaround?

Comment: With plain FTP it works perfect but that is obvious. I keep wondering why login and list/search files works but download don't…